# Can epoxy resin be reused?

Tags: reuse

**Does anybody know if this [epoxy resin](http://uk.farnell.com/electrolube/er2188-50g/potting-compound-gp-epoxy-er-50g/dp/3072149?ost=ER2188%2050G&selectedCategoryId=&categoryNameResp=All&searchView=table&iscrfnonsku=false) can be reused?** I do not need all the resin in the package at this time and I want to store it for later use. I am asking because it says in the specifications that the useable life is 60mins.

If it cannot be reused, is there a resin that can be reused? Or at least, in smaller packages?

Comment: It's totally commonplace, for 50? years, that epoxy is sold in two completely separate packages for the two components.  The link you give is, very confusingly, to a very new, somewhat bizarre, "convenience" product that makes it easy to mix the two parts.  Your question would be rather like you arrived from Mars and asked, for example, "say, are there any cars that run on anything other then batteries?" - !  Or if you were from Mars and asked "Are there any dog breeds other than Labradoodle?"  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After mixing the two parts should be used.
Not be reused.
You can mix the quantity you require keeping the proportion of parts. Store tightly what remains.

Comment: "Store tightly what remains." That means I can use it again in the future, not throw it away. That is what I meant by "reusing". Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I use a kitchen scale to accurately weigh both parts of the resin, and only take what is needed. Unmixed resin components do have a shelf life, but it is pretty long.

Answer (score 7):

Yes and no.

In general, yes, epoxy resin can be re-used. It's supplied in two containers, you measure and mix only what you need, taking great care to avoid cross-contamination when handling the two parts. West Systems and other marine epoxy products are designed for this.

That pack however is intended for easy mixing. If used as intended, that prevents reuse, as you mix it in the pack before opening.

You might be able to decant each part into separate containers, then measure and mix as normal, keeping the rest for future use, but it'll be a messier process than starting from separate containers, and you'd better not expect any guarantees from the supplier if you try.

Comment: what's the trick to store that kind of seringe where you need to break the tip/cap for the first use? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy#/media/File%3AFiveMinEpoxy.jpg

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "re-use" epoxy, don't buy it in "mix-in-the-pack" packaging like your link. Those packs are designed for clean and fast mixing of the whole pack for a single use.

You can buy epoxy with the two components in separate containers, and measure out and mix any quantity you need. The pack often contains a spatula or something similar to use as a mixing and spreading tool - you can mix small amounts the components on almost any disposable material, e.g. a piece of paper. Just be careful not to cross-contaminate the original containers, otherwise you may end up "glueing" the caps onto the containers, etc, which makes re-opening them rather difficult!

Comment: Can you give me an example of epoxy with the two components in separate containers, on Farnell or Mouser?

Comment: Just search either site for "two part epoxy". Though their prices in quantity even make West System 105 look inexpensive.

Comment: Look in your local hardware or "dollar" store for two-part epoxy.  It is very common to see a package with two squeeze tubes or other packaging.

Comment: @lephzero Is there trick to store the kind of seringe where you need to break the tip/cap for the first use? en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy#/media/File%3AFiveMinEpoxy.jpg